# How can I stop jQuery UI dialogs from getting squashed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a fairly simple `div` element which I want to turn into a popup via jQuery UI. The HTML is basically

```
<div id="login_form">
     <table> ... </table>
</div>
```

Without any jQuery involvement, it renders fairly naturally like this (the green background comes from the div and fits around its contents):

[image]

When I make it into a popup with this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#login_form") .dialog (
    {
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#login_or_sign_up") .click (function()
    {
        $("#login_form") .dialog ("open");
    });
});
```

It renders like this.

[image]

Yuck.

I'm fairly sure the reason is simply that I haven't included the jQuery UI CSS files. *I don't want to include the jQuery UI CSS files.*

By inspecting the popup I notice that jQuery has created another div which surrounds the one I provided, and this is styled to have a width of 300px. I expect this is the problem -- jQuery UI has picked a size which is too small and the inner elements are not reducing themselves to fit.

**Can I make jQuery dialog-ify my div without shrinking it?**

If not, I can probably work around this by adding `width:100%` styles to the inner elements individually. In that case, **is there a general workaround which will not require me to alter any of the inner elements?**

Comment: jquery width defaults to 300, see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width). try specifying `.dialog({ width: 'auto' })`. (Or choose another width in pixels if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

`.dialog({ width: 'auto' })` works.